# Getting error while migrating cucumberjs from version 6 to 7

Tags: cucumberjs

Getting an error as:

```
    TS2305: Module '/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib' has no exported member 'HookCode'.   
 import { HookCode } from "@cucumber/cucumber";
```

Now the types are deprecated from version 7 as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cucumber

Answer (score 0):

Found the type as:

```
import { TestCaseHookFunction as HookCode } from "@cucumber/cucumber/lib/support_code_library_builder/types";
```